# Removing code duplication

Tags: java, generics, programming-languages, functional-programming

I am trying to create a little functional programming library for Java (just to scratch my own itch). While defining the [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) for `List`s, `Set`s and `Map`s I have come across this problem: The functions that take a collection, and return a collection of same type have almost the same implementation, and yet have to be redefined for each of the data structure - `List`s, `Set`s, and `Map`s.

For example, here is the implementation of `map` function for `List`s, and `Set`s:

```
public static <A, B> List<B> map(
  List<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  List<B> ys = new ArrayList<B>();
  for(A a : xs) {
    ys.add(transformer.apply(a));
  }
  return ys;
}

public static <A, B> Set<B> map(
  Set<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  Set<B> ys = new HashSet<B>();
  for(A a : xs) {
    ys.add(transformer.apply(a));
  }
  return ys;
}
```

A `filter` function:

```
public static <A> List<A> filter(
  List<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, Boolean> predicate
) {
  List<A> ys = new ArrayList<A>();
  for(A a : xs) {
    if(predicate.apply(a)) {
      ys.add(a);
    }
  }
  return ys;
}

public static <A> Set<A> filter(
  Set<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, Boolean> predicate
) {
  Set<A> ys = new HashSet<A>();
  for(A a : xs) {
    if(predicate.apply(a)) {
      ys.add(a);
    }
  }
  return ys;
}
```

As can be seen from this example, the bodies of the implementations for `Set` and `List` are almost the same.

There are lot many functions like `map` and `filter` in my library, and each of those is defined thrice for each type of collections I am interested in (i.e. `List`, `Set`, and `Map`). This leads to a lot of code duplication, and code smell. I wanted to know whether there's some way in Java that would help me avoid all the code duplication.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

`Func1` is an interface defined as:

```
interface Func1<A, B> {
  public B apply(A a);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you could just use the `Collection` interface, to eliminate separate cases for the `List` and `Set` interfaces.

Comment: @Bears: The problem is this: `map` for `List` should return a `List`, `map` for `Set` should return a `Set` etc.

Comment: So implement for `Collection` with the `List` or `Set` as argument and call that implementation from your `List` and `Set` convenience classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't have higher-order polymorphism (aka higher-kinds) so this is not possible within the type system. Many Java programmers resort to XML and/or reflection (i.e. escape the type system) to address this deficiency.

Scala can deal with this and what you are describing is called a covariant functor. This rather fundamental data type (along with much more) has been implemented in the Scalaz library and includes implementations for java.util.*.

Further, there are many more covariant functors that are not collections and many more functors that are not covariant.

You may wish to google for "20 Intermediate Scala Exercises" if you wish to explore this particular concept further.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static <A, B> List<B> map(
  List<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  List<B> ys = new ArrayList<B>();
  map(xy, transformer, ys);
  return ys;
}

public static <A, B> Set<B> map(
  Set<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  Set<B> ys = new HashSet<B>();
  map(xy, transformer, ys);
  return ys;
}
private static <A, B> map(
  Collection<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer,
  Iterable<B> ys
) {
  for(A a : xs) {
    ys.add(transformer.apply(a));
  }
}
```

Job done.

Note, it's typical of Java APIs, to pass the mutable the collection in, rather than create a new one in the method. Personally, I'm not a fan of mutability at the collection level, but it's what we have to work with (in Java).

(I'm not keen on `A` and `B` as generic parameters with this sort of stuff.)

Or you could use a factory:

```
public static <A, B> List<B> map(
  List<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  return map(xs, transformer, new CollectionFactory<B, List<B>>() {
      public List<B> create() { return new ArrayList<B>(); }
  });
}

public static <A, B> Set<B> map(
  Set<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer
) {
  return map(xs, transformer, new CollectionFactory<B, Set<B>>() {
      public Set<B> create() { return new HashSet<B>(); }
  });
}

private interface CollectionFactory<E, C extends Collection<E>> {
    C create();
}

private static <A, B, C extends Collection<B>> C map(
  Iterable<? extends A> xs, 
  Func1<? super A, ? extends B> transformer,
  CollectionFactory<B, C> factory
) {
  C ys = factory.create();
  for(A a : xs) {
    ys.add(transformer.apply(a));
  }
  return ys;
}
```

(If you can put up with the pointless verbosity of anonymous inner classes.)

If it wasn't for `Collection` then you'd need to put some (ugly) adapter in.

For completeness (though not tested, could do with a few tweaks), an unpleasant solution using inheritance:

```
Set<String> strs = hashSets().map(things, formatter);

...

public static <E> Functions<E, Set<E>> hashSets() {
    return new Functions<E, Set<E>>() {
        protected Set<E> createCollections() {
            return new HashSet<E>();
        }
    };
}

public abstract class Functions<E, C extends Collection<E>> {
    protected abstract C createCollection();

    public <S> C map(
      Set<? extends S> xs, 
      Func1<? super S, ? extends E> transformer
    ) {
      C ys = createCollection();
      for(S a : xs) {
        ys.add(transformer.apply(a));
      }
      return ys;
    }

    public <S> C filter(
      List<? extends S> xs, 
      Func1<? super S, Boolean> predicate // Predicate<? super S> might be nicer!!
    ) {
      C ys = createCollection();
      for(A a : xs) {
        if(predicate.apply(a)) {
          ys.add(a);
        }
      }
      return ys;
    }
}
```

Comment: The API is the same, the new map method is private

Comment: It's still a lot of code duplication. For each new method I might want to add, I'd need to write the private implementation using `Collections` and then a convenience method for each of the data type. Come on, there has to be a better way to do this. :(

Comment: @one-zero-zero-one You would need a method with the common code and a method which decides which implementation to use, yes. You could just use the implementation method. You could use inheritance, but for these sorts of static methods, I'd call that unpleasant.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do better than what Tom has suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709298/help-with-removing-code-duplication/3709448#3709448). Java doesn't support higher-kinded types - a feature that can help you abstract over the collection type and thus avoid duplicating the same code for each of the collection types.

Scala supports this feature, and it's used extensively in its standard library. [This paper](http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/publicaties/doctoraten/cw/CW2009_03.pdf) by Adriaan Moors discusses how Scala avoids this sort of code duplication with help of higher-kinded types.

Two screenshots from the above-mentioned paper:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Java's type system is sophisticated enough to address this, but Scala's is. With the 2.8 version of the collections library, they built a system to automatically create a collection of the appropriate type based on the collection you're working with. So, if you call `filter` on a `List`, it returns a new `List`. Call `filter` on a `Set` and you'll get a `Set` back. It does this while still only having a single implementation of `filter`.

To learn more, take a look at [`Traversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Traversable.html) and the stuff that uses it. I believe [`CanBuildFrom`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom.html) is where a lot of the magic happens.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively a list is just a Monad for a type `T`, giving it the capability to store multiple instances of the type. That's why all the usual laws of monads apply here, so you can implement *all* operations using a `bind` and `return` member.

I'm sorry I don't have the time to explain further for now, but in the .NET space we have SelectMany and Enumerable.Repeat(1, element) for the same purposes. There's a lot of information available about that.

Any operator (such as `filter` in your example) can be implemented using `SelectMay` respectively bind.

Comment: Thanks for the response Johannes but I am not using any functional data structures here. `List` and `Set` in my examples are `java.util.List` and `java.util.Set` respectively.

Comment: sure, but these implement something like IEnumerable or ICollection (the collection monad in this case)

Comment: @Johannes: C# has the exactly same problem here. Their solution was to give up and always return IEnumerable.