# Generic method that takes List in non generic class

Tags: java, list, generics, methods

I want to do something like this

```
private <T extends List<?>> List<?> getFirstFiveElements(T list) {
    //body
}
```

However when I tray to pass in the arguments it is not working

```
List<A> a = new LinkedList<A>;
List<B> b = new LinkedList<B>; 
getFirstFiveElements(a);
getFirstFiveElements(b);
```

so any suggestion how I cam make this work.

Comment: What about a signature like `private <T> List<T> getFirstNElements(Iterable<T> elements, int n)` instead? More flexible and type-safe.

Comment: "it is not working" how is it "not working"? error? warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work just fine.

```
private static <A, T extends List<A>> List<A> getFirstFiveElements(T list) {
   //
}
```

`T` serves no useful purpose here, and therefore can be eliminated.

```
private static <A> List<A> getFirstFiveElements(List<A> list) {
   //
}
```

If you want the method to return the same type that it takes (i.e. `ArrayList` for `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` for `LinkedList`), then sorry to tell you, [Java's type system is not capable of that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715347/192247).

Answer (score 1):

Great 2 second later, I have found the magic combination. Anyway for all of the others who stumble upon this here is what worked for me

```
     private <T> List<T> getStart(List<T> list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use template? Would not be enough to use this:

```
private List<?> getFirstFiveElements(List<?> list) {
    //body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Test {

  private static <T extends List<?>> List<?> getFirstFiveElements(T list) {
    List<Object> result = new LinkedList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i < list.size(); i++) {
      result.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);
    a.add(5);
    a.add(6);
    a.add(7);
    System.out.println(getFirstFiveElements(a));
  }

}
```

Comment: Hrm... it works for me (just re-ran it). What version of Java?