# Scala Generics from C# Perspective -- Higher Kinded Type?

Tags: scala

Dumb question ...

I'm writing something using C# generics and feel like I found a short coming, and that it might be overcome using higher kinded types in Scala, which I'm only vaguely familiar with.

Here is the code:

```
public void Subscribe<P, T>(Action<T> callback) where P : ISubscriberProvider<T>
```

*(Provider is probably a bad term ... I think it might really be a factory)*

So the issue is that I have to provide both P and T in the signature.  Instead I would want something like:

```
public void Subscribe<P<T>>(Action<T> callback) where P : ISubscriberProvider<T>
```

This isn't valid syntax.

Could this be made valid with Scala?

Thanks much!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Show us where you're calling this method. Also, instead of passing callbacks, you might want to look into `Future` objects, or `Akka actors`

Comment: Check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709298/removing-code-duplication. It might help you understand what higher kinds are basically about.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know C#, but it looks like

```
def subscribe[T, P <: SubscriberProvider[T]](fun: T => Unit): Unit
```

but then the type `P` is not used anywhere in the arguments or return type, so not sure what use you can make of it.